# Django 2.0 - Allowing Anonymous User Post Privileges

Tags: django-2.0, anonymous-users

I am new to Django and require some help as to how best to implement an anonymous user within django 2.0.

## The Aim

Essentially I am trying to create a website in which a user can fill out some fields and then this can be split into sub tables. The information they enter is only visible to themself and no other user.

## The Problem

So far I have found that if you allow someone post privileges to the database then they should be an authenticated user. My issue is that I don't want to force people to sign-up just to use this app.

## Questions

With this in mind, I had a look at [Anonymous users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#authorization-for-anonymous-users) in the documentation but I am not able to make much sense of it.

- Should I be creating my own model that extends AnonymousUser?
- What are some of the security issues with this approach?
- If the user closes the browser and reopens, will they be able to view their previously entered information?
- If the user wanted to sign-up at a later date, is it possible to
  maintain their information?

Thanks for any help